# Accessing a widget from a different frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I searched on this website and other websites, and I still cannot figure out how to change the text of a label residing on a different frame. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class mainW(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.widgets()
    def widgets(self):
        self.left = leftF(self)
        self.left.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.right = rightF(self)
        self.right.grid(row=0, column=1)

class leftF(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="blue")
        self.parent = parent
        self.leftWidgets()
    def leftWidgets(self):
        self.Label = Label(self, text="Hello", bg="red", fg="white")
        self.Label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

class rightF(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="white")
        self.parent = parent
        self.rightWidgets()
    def rightWidgets(self):
        self.Button = Button(self, text="change text", bg="yellow", fg="black", command=self.action)
        self.Button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    def action(self):
        self.targetFrame = leftF(self)
        self.targetLabel = self.targetFrame.Label
        self.targetLabel.config(text="World")

if __name__=="__main__":
    mainW(None).mainloop()
```

Essentially, the action that is assigned to the button residing on **rightF** should change the text of the label on **leftF**. If anyone can direct me to the right direction, I would really appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: as with any other python object, all you need is a reference to that object.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's what I am doing with self.targetFrame.Label, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Unfortunately you are not! You are creating a new object with self.targetFrame = leftF(self). You have to reference the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new object with

```
self.targetFrame = leftF(self)
```

and not referencing the original one. Change the action function to

```
    def action(self):
        self.parent.left.Label.config(text="World")
```

and it will work.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.